# Knockjs mapped array not attached to parent object

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-2.0

I use knockoutjs.mapping to map an existing object return be the server is JSON.

The object is similar to the cart editor [example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html), the main difference in the items already exists.

Here is my attempt http://jsfiddle.net/9ej3r/

mapping is straight-forward:

```
var mapping = {
            'Items': {
                create: function(options) {
                    return new InvoiceItem(options.data);
                },
                key: function(data){
                    return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(data.ID);
                }
            }
        };
```

when i click remove, i get the error: "this.Items in undefined"

what am i doing wrong here? how can adapt the cart editor example to work with existing lines ?

Comment: Add your view model and html to fiddle.

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you whats wrong with your remove function when you don't post it?

Comment: sorry, i corrected the jsFiddle link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have been bitten by the fact how `this` works in javascript.

Because when your `removeItem` method gets called the `this` will be the actual item e.g. an `InvoiceItem` not the `Invoice` so you need to capture the "other" `this` in a variable and use that in your function to access the `Invoice`.

So your `removeItem` should look like this:

```
var self = this;

this.removeItem = function (item) { 
   self.Items.remove(item);
}
```

See also this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nemesv/zs3UU/).

You should note that the [cart editor example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html) also uses this technique in the `removeLine` method

```
var self = this;
self.removeLine = function(line) { self.lines.remove(line) };
```